# How can I use variables in a picture's file name and loops to open multiple pictures using pygame without cluttering the code

Tags: python, image, for-loop, variables, pygame

```
import easygui, sys, random, time, tkinter, pygame

Running = True
while Running is True:
```

Creates screen and loads 11 pictures for simulation, how can I use a loop and variables to de-clutter the code? The only difference between each .png file is the frame_XX part of the image file. I have tried to implement variables into the file names but it never works.

```
 pygame.init()
    loading_screen = pygame.display.set_mode([600, 300])   
    loading_screen.fill([0, 0, 0])
    pygame.display.set_caption("Student Planner 2")
    LoadBar1 = pygame.image.load("frame_00_delay-0.06s.png")
    LoadBar2 = pygame.image.load("frame_01_delay-0.06s.png")
    LoadBar3 = pygame.image.load("frame_02_delay-0.06s.png")
    LoadBar4 = pygame.image.load("frame_03_delay-0.06s.png")
    LoadBar5 = pygame.image.load("frame_04_delay-0.06s.png")
    LoadBar6 = pygame.image.load("frame_05_delay-0.06s.png")
    LoadBar7 = pygame.image.load("frame_06_delay-0.06s.png")
    LoadBar8 = pygame.image.load("frame_07_delay-0.06s.png")
    LoadBar9 = pygame.image.load("frame_08_delay-0.06s.png")
    LoadBar10 = pygame.image.load("frame_09_delay-0.06s.png")
    LoadBar11 = pygame.image.load("frame_10_delay-0.06s.png")
```

Create loading screen animation by flipping the display for all eleven pictures then closes the program when the loop is over, same question here: how can I use loops and variables to de-clutter the code.

```
for looper in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    loading_screen.blit(LoadBar1, (100, 150))
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    pygame.display.flip()
    loading_screen.blit(LoadBar2, (100, 150))
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    pygame.display.flip()
    loading_screen.blit(LoadBar3, (100, 150))
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    pygame.display.flip()
    loading_screen.blit(LoadBar4, (100, 150))
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    pygame.display.flip()
    loading_screen.blit(LoadBar5, (100, 150))
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    pygame.display.flip()
    loading_screen.blit(LoadBar6, (100, 150))
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    pygame.display.flip()
    loading_screen.blit(LoadBar7, (100, 150))
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    pygame.display.flip()
    loading_screen.blit(LoadBar8, (100, 150))
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    pygame.display.flip()
    loading_screen.blit(LoadBar9, (100, 150))
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    pygame.display.flip()
    loading_screen.blit(LoadBar10, (100, 150))
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    pygame.display.flip()
    loading_screen.blit(LoadBar11, (100, 150))
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
Running = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initialization of `LoadBar`s can be done in a loop and into a list instead:

```
for i in range(11):
    LoadBar[i] = pygame.image.load("frame_%02d_delay-0.06s.png" % i)
```

so that the entire animation loop can be done with a nested `for` loop that iterates over the `LoadBar` list:

```
for _ in range(5):
    for loadbar in LoadBar:
        loading_screen.blit(loadbar, (100, 150))
        pygame.time.delay(20)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thanks! Would of never thought of it like that.